# Comparing DataRows, adding table values dynamically

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I think it best I explain my scenario first.

I bring all my data back from a sql database, using SqlDataAdapters, within on transaction.

In an example, I have a college. I want open this college and add modules, and at the same time I wish to add students to these new modules.

These modules and students are saved to their respective DataTable, and the student table has a column relating to it's parent module, "moduleid".

My problem is that I need a way to save both of these in the same transaction, adding the new moduleid to it's child rows. I can create the new modules, and their own moduleid in it's datatable is updated, however when I now need to save the students to this module, I need to add it's moduleid, otherwise it's added to the database without one.

This is my effort so far but I feel I'm barking up the wrong tree.

```
            DataTable dt_new_modules = ds_College.Tables["module"].GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
            da_modules.Update(ds_College.Tables["module"]);
            ds_College.Tables["module"].AcceptChanges();

            DataTable dt_added = ds_College.Tables["student"].GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
            if (dt_added != null)
            {
                if (dt_new_modules != null)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow new_module in dt_new_modules.Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow updated_module in ds_College.Tables["module"].Rows)
                        {
                            if (updated_module.Equals(new_module))
                            {
                                foreach (DataRow new_student in dt_added.Rows)
                                {
                                    if ((int)new_student["moduleid"] == (int)new_module["moduleid"])
                                        new_student["moduleid"] = (int)updated_module["moduleid"];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                da_student.Update(dt_added);
                dt_added.AcceptChanges();
            }

            DataTable dt_modified = ds_College.Tables["student"].GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
            if (dt_modified != null)
            {
                da_student.Update(dt_modified);
                dt_modified.AcceptChanges();
            }
```

I am trying to loop through all the added users and if the datarow is the same as the one before it was given it's new moduleid, then get the new id and give it to the user, however I feel there must be a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right, your problem is with inserting child records for a parent module which was not yet inserted to the DB. I had somewhat the same issue, and using SqlCommandBuilder instead made it work.

Create **SqlCommandBuilder** (System.Data.SqlClient) objects for each table you are changing, passing the corresponding sqlAdapter as a parameter to the constructor.

It creates the INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE commands automatically, and will handle all the changes made in memory back to the database.

After the command builder objects are created, just call "Update" on the data adapter you had for the parent table (modules), and afterwards "Update" on the children table data adapter.

Hope this solves it.

Comment: There appears to be no "Update" method for a command builder object. Is this the correct class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I meant calling "Update" on the data adapters.

Comment: In a short, the sql command builder objects will create the insert, update and delete sql statements required for reflecting any in-memory changes in the database. To effect the changes, call the "update" method on your data adapters, but do so taking into consideration the table you need updated first, i.e., the parent table [your parent  table DataAdapter here].Update() - and afterwards [your children table DataAdapter here].Update().

Comment: Any chance you can provide an example of this functionality? I have added 2 SqlCommandBuilder's, but I think I need to be doing something more than just:SqlCommandBuilder cb_module = new SqlCommandBuilder(da_module);
            SqlCommandBuilder cb_student = new SqlCommandBuilder(da_student);
adding these before I call the DataAdapters update() and acceptchanges() methods.

Comment: Sorry, all that I do here is really: a) instantiante the DataAdapters; b) call "Fill" in them; c) perform my logic for deletion, insertion and update of records in the data tables; d) call "Update" in the data adapters, first on the parent table(s) and afterwards on the children ones.

Comment: Are you getting an exception when adding the students? If so, what is it?

Comment: I was not getting an exception, however I have now sorted this issue. Thank you for your help @Veverke